# Change one character in PostgreSQL column string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a hundreds of entries in a description column that look like the following:

```
CAP 0.001UF ±10% 50V X7R 0402
```

I need to change it to:

```
CAP 0.001UF +/-10% 50V X7R 040
```

How can I search through the records and change all instances of `±` to `+/-`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using replace() and `like`?

```
update t
    set description = replace(description, '±', '+/-')
    where description like '%±%';
```

Comment: And if all rows has a ±, you can skip the where clause.